# Passing Oozie coordinator workflow parameters to the workflow

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I have a workflow which consists of a shell script and a HQL script.
I've set a workflow parameter called CURRENT_TS to ${ coord:nominalTime()}

How do I address CURRENT_TS in my HQL/bash script ?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to define a parameter in the following jobs and simply set it to the the workflow propery name (in my example ${CURRENT_TS})